# How can we disable saved passwords pop-up from Login fields

Tags: authentication, popup, passwords

i have recently created a login form, but my client wants to disable the saved passwords popup from login input, how can i disable this?!

Disabling saved passwords pop from login form input fields.
please provide the code to disable saved passwords pop-up from login form input fields.